# How do I return an array instead of a task?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, task

In my ActivitySignup, I want to call the `createUser` function (from my Firestore class). I want `createUser` to return `result` and `message` to ActivitySignup. This will keep my ActivitySignup very clean. How do I do this?

**ActivitySignup:**

```
class ActivitySignup : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var user: String
    private lateinit var userEditTxt: EditText
    private lateinit var email: String
    private lateinit var emailEditTxt: EditText
    private lateinit var password: String
    private lateinit var passwordEditTxt: EditText
    private lateinit var backbutton: Button
    private lateinit var terms: CheckBox
    private lateinit var submitbutton: Button
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var currentDateTime: DateTime
    private val tag: String = "ActivitySignup"
    private lateinit var functions: FirebaseFunctions
    private lateinit var fs: FS

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)

        fs = FS()

        submitbutton = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)

        submitbutton.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.e(tag,"Clicked submit")

            userEditTxt = findViewById(R.id.et_user)
            user = userEditTxt.text.toString().trim()
            emailEditTxt = findViewById(R.id.et_email)
            email = emailEditTxt.text.toString().trim()
            passwordEditTxt = findViewById(R.id.et_password)
            password = passwordEditTxt.text.toString().trim()

            if (user.isNotEmpty() && email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
//                fs.createUser(user, email, password)
//                    .continueWith { task ->
//                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
//                            Log.e(tag, "createUser task succeeded")
////                            Log.e(tag, "Result1: ${task.result?.get("result")}") //case sensitive
////                            Log.e(tag, "Result2: ${task.result. ("message")}") //case sensitive
//
//                            val taskResult = task.result //.get("result")
//                            val result = taskResult.getData
//                            val message = task.result?.get("message")
//
//                            val intent = Intent(this, ActivityGroups::class.java)
//                            startActivity(intent)
//                            finish()
//                        } else {
//                            Log.e(tag, "createUser task failed")
//                        }
//                    }
                var returnResult = fs.createUser(user, email, password)
                Log.e(tag, "returnResult[0]: ${returnResult[0]}")
                Log.e(tag, "returnResult[1]: ${returnResult[1]}")
                //Code continues only if result = 1...


            }

        }

    }

}
```

**FS.createUser():**

```
fun createUser(user: String, email: String, password: String): Array<String> {
        Log.e(tag, "createUser()")
        val functions = Firebase.functions
        val auth = Firebase.auth
        var result: String
        var message: String

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .continueWith() { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.e(tag, "auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() successful")

                    var data = hashMapOf<String, String>()
                    data["user"] = user
                    data["email"] = email

                    functions.getHttpsCallable("createUser").call(data)
                        .continueWith() { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                Log.e(tag, "CF_createUser task was successful")
                                Log.e(tag, "CF_createUser: ${task.result?.data.toString()}")
                                var returnData = task.result?.data.toString()
                                result = returnData[0].toString()
                                message = returnData[1].toString()
                                
                            } else {
                                Log.e(tag, "CF_createUser task failed")
                                Log.e(tag, "CF_createUser exception message: ${task.exception?.message}")
                                Log.e(tag, "CF_createUser exception localizedMessage: ${task.exception?.localizedMessage}")
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Log.e(tag, "auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() failed")
                    Log.e(tag, "authTask exception: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                }

            }
        return arrayOf(result, message)
    }
```

Comment: The error you are getting is self explanatory, as you have not given the result parameter any initial value. A different action that you can take is to pass a callback method to your createUser function and make it accept two arguments, result and message.

Comment: @tomerpacific I should mention that I'm a beginner. Not sure I understand what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look here:

```
val functions = Firebase.functions
val auth = Firebase.auth
var result: String
var message: String
```

Unlike function and auth, result and message are not initialized with a value (i.e. they don't have a value). You can initialize them with initial values like this:

```
var result: String = ""
var message: String = ""
```

or [late-initialize](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) them like this:

```
lateinit var result: String
lateinit var message: String
```

That means these var will get a value as your code processes.

Update on the updated issue:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                //Call your cloud function here
                //If Cloud functions returns desired response, proceed
                return arrayOf(result, message)
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I do your first method, `FS.createUser()` passes back empty strings to ActivitySignup, but this is not right because it should be passing back `result = "1"`. My question is basically about scope. How do I fill a variable using a task and then pass that variable back to ActivitySignup?

Comment: All you have to do is add `1` to the return, you should be able to adapt his suggestions, no? to clarify, `1` is not a standard return type for this procedure.

Comment: @DIGIByte I want to return `result` and `message` which come from the cloud function in the backend. I don't want to hardcode a 1, I want to run the auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword and if that is successful then run the createUser cloud function which returns `result` and `message`. I want these values, whatever they may be, to ActivitySignup so that the code on ActivitySignup is very clean.

Comment: there is no result or message on a successful creation, it simply signs you in. it only returns a message on failure

Comment: @DIGIByte `result` and `message` come from a custom backend cloud function. If auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is successful -> run custom backend cloud function which returns `result` and `message` -> if `result = 1`...rest of code.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I don't see any context of cloud function. Can you provide more details so we can know what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yea I just realized after explaining that I missed the part of the CF. Added.

Comment: @Dharmaraj does my edit make sense? I want to deal with only a 1 or a 0 in my activity so that the code on the activity is very concise and clean.

Comment: This isn't about auth creation but a cloud function that is triggered after the user is created. these are two very different things. Can you update with a snippet of the cloud functions and have you imported the cloud functions?

Comment: @DIGIByte correct, this is more so about tasks and scope in Android/kotlin. The body of the cloud function doesn't matter. All it does is either return a 1 if successful or 0 if unsuccessful (and if 0, it returns a message in the `message` variable). Basically, I'm trying to understand how a veteran in the industry would run the auth function and then a backend function as cleanly as possible.

Comment: This isn't even a scoping issue, this is related to chaining tasks. this question answered your original. you will want to wrap your createUser in Kotlins version of a then() promise
`something { it -> //... }` I think @Dharmaraj is capable of answering sufficiently

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you need to add an onCompleteListener and then check if the task was succesful .Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Dharmaraj that's what I had in the beginning. I tried doing that but it wasn't letting me return `result` and `message` because it was saying it needed to be initialized. However, I know that initialization wasn't really the problem because what I really needed from those values was to capture the values sent back from the cloud function.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you should provide the complete code whatever you had tried. You may think something is wrong while returning but the issue could be how are are calling the function, etc. Please edit and add your code .

Comment: @Dharmaraj ok I rolled back the edits to show the original code.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat you should add this line `return arrayOf(result, message)` right after `message = returnData[1].toString()`.

Comment: @Dharmaraj if I do that it gives an error that says `return is not allowed here`.